# Microsoft Bot Framework: Determining user's Web Chat session availability

Tags: botframework, bots

My scenario is to send an event or message to user's session to check if he is active or not.
I have the conversationId, Bot Channel Account and user connection details already.
I followed the same steps as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958752/microsoft-bot-framework-webchat-c-sharp).

The issue that see is, irrespective of whether user is active or not, i always get ConversationId as the response, which does'nt help me to determine the session availability. I think, my event or message is getting ignored if session is not available.

Can somebody help me here please?

**Adding more information :**

My requirement is to update the status of all the inactive users.
I have all the respective conversationIds of the sessions that these users were part of.
To determine whether user is still active on web chat(meaning, he has'nt closed the webchat window), I am sending an event activity from bot to that user's session by providing the conversationId that we have for that session.
Below is the sample code snippet.

```
var eventActivity = Activity.CreateEventActivity();
eventActivity.From = user.Bot.ChannelAccount;
eventActivity.Recipient = user.Connection.ChannelAccount;
eventActivity.Conversation = user.Connection.ConversationAccount;
eventActivity.Value = userSession;
eventActivity.Name = message.Name;
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(user.Connection.ServiceLink));
var response = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)eventActivity).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

userSession here contains two properties UPN and ConversationId that uniquely identifies the session.
Also, This UserSession's ConversationId is same as user.Connection.ConversationAccount.ConversationId.
Below image contains the User.Bot and user.Connection objects.

[Bot&Connection_Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdiQ2.png)

Comment: Can you explain what functionally would qualify as an active session for you? Which channel and SDK you are using along with some code will also help in solving this issue. Sending a plain event will cause the session to respond normally, which is to say it will acknowledge the receipt of the event by sending back the conversationId. It will likely be easiest (but also most open-ended) to implement such an event response in webchat.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Updated question with more details.

Comment: Would an event that is sent on closing the webchat window fit this use case?